# Get row's values from an image in linux+bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, imagemagick, screenshot

simple question (for you) here.

I have a webcam 720p. I can take easily a screenshot of this webcam via command line (1280x720, yo). My problem is: I don't need the entire picture, but only 1 row 1280x1. Yo bros: how can I save this row (and not the entire picture) via command line?

Comment: You could use imagemagick. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

Comment: Thank you for you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use ImageMagick. If you want the middle row of the image, you would use this:

```
convert image.png -crop 1280x1+0+360 line.jpg
```

If you want that as text with RGB values that you can parse:

```
convert image.png -crop 1280x1+0+360 -colorspace RGB -depth 8 txt:
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1280,1,255,rgb
0,0: (70,38,50)  #462632  rgb(70,38,50)
1,0: (58,28,49)  #3A1C31  rgb(58,28,49)
2,0: (59,43,58)  #3B2B3A  rgb(59,43,58)
3,0: (53,31,37)  #351F25  rgb(53,31,37)
4,0: (57,26,50)  #391A32  rgb(57,26,50)
5,0: (44,75,33)  #2C4B21  rgb(44,75,33)
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for you beautiful answer. It's very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `convert` command in the `imagemagick` package.

```
convert input_file -crop WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF output_file
```

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop)

Comment: Thank you guys for you answer.